# putting jekyll tags in an "onclick" breaks

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, jekyll

in jekyll, this works:

```
---
layout: default
---
    <div class="brief">
        <ul>
            {% for post in site.posts %}
                <li class="postlist">
                    <a href="#" onclick='document.getElementById("one").innerHTML="{{post.url}}";'>{{post.title}}</a>
                    <p>{{post.meta}} <br>{{post.date}} <br>{{post.category}}</p>                
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="post" id="one"></div>
```

but when i change line #8 to:

```
<a href="#" onclick='document.getElementById("one").innerHTML="{{post.content}}";'>{{post.title}}</a>
```

it breaks. why does this happen and what can i do to change this and get the desired outcome?

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what breaks?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your post content is creating invalid HTML (e.g. ending the `onclick` quotes).

In my opinion, a better method to achieve this would be to render all the post content hidden, and have your `onclick` toggle a class to display the relevant content. This would save you from the untold horrors of encoding and decoding that content through an attribute value.

For example:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick='document.getElementById("post-content-{{ forloop.index }}").classList.toggle("hidden")'>{{ post.title }}</a>

    <p>{{ post.meta }} <br>{{ post.date }} <br>{{ post.category }}</p>
    <p id="post-content-{{ forloop.index }}" class="hidden">{{ post.content }}</p>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

External CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

You could also extend this to hide all content sections first, so only one is shown at a time.

Comment: thanks! this works but there is a glitch, the "hidden" toggles back after a second and the div becomes invisible again. any ideas?

Comment: You could try the `remove` method instead of `toggle`. If it's still toggling back after that, then something else on your site could be interfering with it.